# How to display elements inline?

Tags: css, css-selectors, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

Hi i have small problem with CSS that dont know how to resolve.

On my [WHMCS template](https://webradio-solutions.com/inscrit/index.php?language=english) i wanted to implement one element more, and now one element goes in row bellow (Get support). How to fix this?

[image]

This is CSS from that element:

```
.home-shortcuts {
margin: 0;
/*background:#25a2c7;*/
background: #5E35B1;
padding-left: 250px;
margin-top: -60px;
color: #fff
}
```

and this is code from header.tpl file

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a id="btnOrderHosting" href="cart.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
                            <p>
                                Créer une radio <span>&raquo;</span>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {if $registerdomainenabled || $transferdomainenabled}
                        <li>
                            <a id="btnBuyADomain" href="domainchecker.php">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                <p>
                                    {$LANG.buyadomain} <span>&raquo;</span>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {/if}
                    <li>
                        <a id="btnOrderHosting" href="cart.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-hdd-o"></i>
                            <p>
                                {$LANG.orderhosting} <span>&raquo;</span>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="btnMakePayment" href="clientarea.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                            <p>
                                {$LANG.makepayment} <span>&raquo;</span>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="btnGetSupport" href="submitticket.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            <p>
                                {$LANG.getsupport} <span>&raquo;</span>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Some advice how to show all in one row?

Comment: no one can answer you untill you share the code...

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in one of these? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Comment: @aneez-ljaz updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that your li elements are 24% width. Reduce them to 20% (100 / 5 = 20, and you have five items in your list). That's it.

```
.home-shortcuts li {
  width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
.home-shortcuts{padding-left:0;}
.home-shortcuts .container{width:60%;}
.home-shortcuts li {
  width: 20%;
}
```

make `col-md-12` instead of `col-md-8` it'll come fine[image]